# .remove() function not working as expected jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my project, I have a series of inputs, all of type radio button. I want to add functionality where these inputs can be deleted simply by clicking on the little bubble (the bubble that a radio button is). Here is my code so that I can do this:

```
$('#newAnswers input').click(function(){ 
    var $textToDelete = $(this).val();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

the reason why I'm assigning the value of the radio button to a `textToDelete` variable is that usually when you have radio buttons in HTML, you'll have text next to it to describe what that radio button is for. I'm creating a variable to hold this value so that I can delete it from the div manually because the code above works only for removing the radio button, and not the description (or I suppose you could call it the value as well) next to it. The code above also works as expected. HOWEVER, once I implement the functionality to delete the description (or value) next to radio button, the code doesn't work as expected. Here is my implementation:

```
$('#newAnswers input').click(function(){ 
    var $textToDelete = $(this).val();
    $(this).remove();

    // NEW LINE
    $('#newAnswers').html($('#newAnswers').html().replace($textToDelete, ''));
});
```

With this click function, after you click a radio button, it deletes, but if you click a second, or a third, or a fourth, or so on, the radio buttons will NOT delete. In fact, clicking on them only fills them in (or bubbles them in) as if you're just selecting a radio button normally. However, the FIRST radio button you click with this function works as expected. However, any radio buttons you click after that will not delete and I don't know why.

HTML Structure:

```
<div id='newAnswers'>
    <input type="radio" value="answer1" name="question">answer1<br>
    <input type="radio" value="answer2" name="question">answer2<br>
    <input type="radio" value="answer3" name="question">answer3<br>
    <input type="radio" value="answer4" name="question">answer4<br>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to just modify the HTML like that. Why not have a separate element housing the descriptions and deleting adjacent elements?

Comment: Will you show us the HTML structure?

Comment: Enclose both button and text in a separate element (div or span) then in your click handler, remove the parent element where it will remove both inner elements.

Comment: not even a snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add span to the text,

```
<input type="radio" value="answer1" name="question"><span>answer1</span><br>
```

then

```
$('#newAnswers input').click(function(){ 
    $(this).next().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a DOM Element you can use `.remove()` function. this is the usage of `.remove()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.removebut').click(function(){
    $('.removeme').remove();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="removeme">Click to remove me</div>
<button class="removebut">Remove</button>
```

Or if you want to remove the value of input, you can set value to "" with jquery `.val()`function.

usage of `.val()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.removebut').click(function(){
    $('.removeme').val("");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="removeme" value="Click To Remove"/>
<button class="removebut">Remove</button>
```